# How to Skip rows in a SQL Server Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

One I selected the query from my `product` table with an additional Row_Number() column (Num), I'm getting the answer like below (I limited only 20 rows to retrieve).

### Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProductCode) AS Num, 
             ProductName
      FROM   BASE_Product 
      WHERE IsActive = 1) BASE_Product 
WHERE Num > 0 
AND   Num < (21)
```

### Result

[image]

My requirement is how to skip each and every 3 rows and retrieve only 7 limit rows.

### Expected result

I need the result such as below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql) operator for this purpose.

> **Modulo**
>   Returns the remainder of one number divided by another.

In this case:

```
WHERE (Num - 1) % 4 = 0
```

I've set up a sample, generating a series of 1K integers.

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> -- ② Integers table
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> with
>   p0(i) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
> , p1(i) as (select 1 from p0 as a, p0 as b, p0 as c, p0 as d, p0 as e)--1K rows
> select row_number() over(order by i) as val
> into integers
> from p1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 1024 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select top 25 * 
> from integers
> where (val - 1) % 4 = 0
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | val |
> | :-- |
> | 1   |
> | 5   |
> | 9   |
> | 13  |
> | 17  |
> | 21  |
> | 25  |
> | 29  |
> | 33  |
> | 37  |
> | 41  |
> | 45  |
> | 49  |
> | 53  |
> | 57  |
> | 61  |
> | 65  |
> | 69  |
> | 73  |
> | 77  |
> | 81  |
> | 85  |
> | 89  |
> | 93  |
> | 97  |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1ed7aacfa5a2515205030ca4090723e1)*

Comment: Thanks. 

Another Problem is if i want to retrieve value that start from 4, 8, 12, etc. how can i do..

Comment: Start From Val 4, after 8, 12, 16, 20.. (retrieve value not from the beginning such as 1)

Comment: The change it: `where (val) % 4 = 0`

Answer (score 2):

Add another condition

```
AND Num % 4 = 1
```

Or simply list all the values:

```
WHERE Num IN (1,5,9,13,17,21,25)
```